# reg. KOrganizer

Tags: kubuntu, 14.10, korganizer

I use KOrganizer with Kubuntu 14.10. No matter how often I try to establish colours for the categories, they do not show. Whenever I tip-in a new date in the calender, it does not show the choosen category - nor the choosen colour. It is not possible to create a new category on the bottom of the input-tab for the task. I saved my tasks in an "i.cal" date which I can open as a new calender or import into an existing one. However it shows all tasks and dates, I can see the summary of all categories that I establishes, but the category does not show on the bottom of the task-tab nor does it show the color I choose. Where and how does KOrganizer save these parameters?